# No main manifest attribute, in server.jar

Tags: java

I am trying to compile and run a .jar file from multiple .java files through terminal, no IDE is used.

Files in directory:

```
Board.java  
ChessLabel.java  
ChessPart.java  
Controller.java  
King.java  
manifest.txt  
Pawn.java  
Prize.java  
Rook.java  
Screen.java  
UDPServer.java
```

manifest.txt file contents:
Main-Class: UDPServer

```
>javac *.java  
>jar cvfm server.jar manifest.txt *.class


no main manifest attribute, in server.jar
```

Comment: In `manifest.txt`, make sure you press enter at the end of the last line of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
jar cfe server.jar UDPServer *.class
```

Comment: That is another way of doing it, but doesn't explain why the seemingly valid `manifest.txt` file isn't working.